# Creating patch from git repository interactivelly

Tags: git, git-patch

I have a repository where I have a commit I would like to publish as a patch to an open source project. The problem is that some parts of that commit have debugging information I need and want to keep for myself, but represent clutter to this public repository.

What I am looking for is to produce a patch file from my repository through a similar mechanic as the `git add -up`, where I can select which parts of the differences are going to be staged for commit. Is there any way to this to produce a patch I can send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `git add -up`:

- Check out a new branch based on your work.
- Reset it back to the parent of your work, e.g., something like `git reset master`.  This will rewind the repository *without* making changes to your working copy.
- Now use `git add -up` to add your changes.
- Commit the changes, and now you can `git format-patch master` to get your patch.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to this to produce a patch I can send?

Sure. Commit what you have, create a new branch based on your current branch (like `git checkout -b NewBranchName`) and edit out the parts you don't want to publish. When you're ready, consider rebasing to squash your commits down to just one commit, and then create a pull request from `NewBranchName`. Then you can go back to your previous branch and still have all the debug stuff intact.